# Rails5.2: avoid N+1 when loading multiples models with resized attachments

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, query-performance, rails-activestorage

I've 4 models (Album, Samplepack, Demo & Ghostproduction) that I'd like to display in a single view. Two of them (Album and Samplepack) has a cover image attached.

Here's the resulting flow :

- StaticController => loads 4 models into @resources
- index.html.erb (view) => display @resources
- application_helper (#display_mosaic) => find the resource corresponding partial
- hoverable_< resource> => display the resource partial (
- < resource>.large => resize the attached picture

---

The controller loading 4 models :

```rb
# app/controllers/static_controller

class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @resources = [
      Album.all.with_attached_album_artwork,
      Samplepack.all.with_attached_album_artwork,
      Demo.all,
      Ghostproduction.all
    ].flatten
  end
end
```

The view where @resources are display:

```rb
# app/views/static/index.html.erb

<% @resources.sort_by(&:created_at).each do |resources| %>
  <%= display_mosaic(resource) %>
<% end %>
```

The corresponding helper:

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def display_mosaic(item)
  if item.class == Demo
    return render('demos/hoverable_demo', demo: item)
  elsif item.class == Samplepack
    return render('samplepacks/hoverable_samplepack', samplepack: item)
#  ... and so on
end
```

Exemple of a partial:

```rb
# app/views/albums/_hoverable_album.html.erb

<div>
  <%= image_tag album.large if album.album_artwork.attached? %>
</div>
```

And the ActiveStorage variant:

```rb
# app/models/concerns/artworkable_concern.rb

def large
  return self.album_artwork.variant(resize: '600x600').processed
end
```

---

Using this solution, it results in **14 queries**:

```rb
# logs

# Album.all.with_attached_album_artwork
  Album Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums"
  # Album attachments
    ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" IN ($3, $4, $5, $6)  [["record_type", "Album"], ["name", "album_artwork"], ["record_id", 1], ["record_id", 2], ["record_id", 3], ["record_id", 4]]
    ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2], ["id", 3], ["id", 6]]

# Samplepack.all.with_attached_album_artwork
  Samplepack Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "samplepacks".* FROM "samplepacks"
  # Samplepack attachments
    ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Samplepack"], ["name", "album_artwork"], ["record_id", 1]]
    ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]

# Demo.all
  Demo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "demos".* FROM "demos"

# Ghostproduction.all
  Ghostproduction Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "ghostproductions".* FROM "ghostproductions"

# User, because of some logic in my _navbar partial
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 

# Variants (.large), I believe it's a N+1 issue (I currently have 4 Album + 1 Samplepack attachments to resize)
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (21.0ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Is there any way to reduce the amount of query and boost this view performance ? I've read about Eager Loading but it doesn't seem to be appropriate (there's no relationship between those models).
As a beginner a helping hand would be gratefully appreciated.

Have a good day,
Clément

---

**EDIT:** I've found this [great guide from EvilMartian](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond)

**EDIT2:** [Another resource](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/some-notes-on-whats-going-on-in-activestorage/) (more exhaustive)

Comment: Does `with_attached_album_artwork` includes the activestorage attachment?

Comment: Yes it does. When I run `Album.all.with_attached_album_artwork` it fires 3 queries : 1) all Albums, 2) ActiveStorage::Attachment, 3) ActiveStorage::Blob. I may be wrong but I believe it's the minimum amount of query I could do. (EDIT: I've edited the log in my question to make it clearer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything's got an image attachment, then you could turn your thinking inside out and just load the attachments directly, with an includes for the polymorphic record. Attachments are ActiveRecord models too. You might have:

```
@resources =
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.
    where(record_type: %w[Album Samplepack Demo Production]).
    includes(:record).
    map(&:record)
```

for the main data fetch.  It won't be one query, but Rails'll optimise this to be the minimum number of queries (one for all the attachments, and one to load each type in the polymorphic collection).

For the variant, the blob query might be unstoppable without a patch to Rails.  The alternative to tying yourself in knots over N+1 queries is caching and in fact [DHH even recommends it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktZLpjCanvg).  I'd wrap an appropriate `cache` around it ([documentation here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache)). Naively, that'd be:

```
<% @resources.sort_by(&:created_at).each do |resource| %>
  <% cache resource do %>
    <%= display_mosaic(resource) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, take a good hard look at your `display_mosaic` method as well, because it looks to me like it's re-implementing the built-in polymorphic partial rendering logic. With a bit of jiggling filenames around, you might be able to replace that with:

```
<%= render partial: @resources.sort_by(&:created_at), cached: true %>
```

for super efficient rendering.

Alternatively, and this is a fairly common pattern for front pages, use a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rules-materializedviews.html) that's a union query and has its own ActiveRecord model. You can manage views in Rails with the [Scenic gem](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer (and sorry for the delay). Querying ActiveStorage::Attachment was exactly what I was looking for ! Is that better to sort an instance variable inside the view (`@resources.sort_by(&:created_at)`) or to ask the controller to set another dedicated variable (`@sorted_resources = @resources.sort_by(&:created_at)`, or another query) ?

Comment: In general I prefer to minimise the number of instance variables and treat sorting as a view consideration. If data in an association has a natural order, then it’s best declared in a scope or other domain model method. Either way, controllers always end up seeming like the exactly wrong place to be explicitly sorting anything.